# xltabular correct spacing

Tags: spacing, captions, xltabular

I use this template: https://github.com/andygrunwald/FOM-LaTeX-Template
Now i try to create a table:

```latex
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}[H]{|l|l|X|l|l|l|}
    \caption{Literaturrecherche}\label{tbl:literaturrecherche} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Plattform} & \textbf{Abfrage} & \textbf{Literatur} & \textbf{H-Index} & \textbf{Q-Ranking} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
    \multicolumn{5}{|l|}{\leftarrow\ \tablename\ \thetable: Literaturrecherche} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Plattform} & \textbf{Abfrage} & \textbf{Literatur} & \textbf{H-Index} & \textbf{Q-Ranking} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline
    \multicolumn{5}{|r|}{Fortsetzung \rightarrow} \\
    \hline
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
\end{xltabular}
```

It works fine and looks clean.
Only now I have a problem with the caption. It sticks directly to the table and leaves no space like normal tables. How can i add the same spacing?
The spacing is created by:

```latex
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
```

```latex
\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Plattformen}\label{tbl:plattformen}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[ht]{|l|X|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Plattform} & \textbf{Addresse} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image: correct caption spacing]

[image: wrong caption spacing]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, font=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\usepackage{tabularx}% für Breitenangabe
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{nicefrac} % Brüche
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating} % vertikal schreiben
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Plattformen}\label{tbl:plattformen}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[ht]{|l|X|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Plattform} & \textbf{Addresse} \newline \\
        \hline
        ACM & dl.acm.org \\
        \hline
        Emerald & emerald.com/insight \\
        \hline
        Google Scholar & scholar.google.com \\
        \hline
        IEEE Xplore & ieeexplore.ieee.org \\
        \hline
        Mendeley & mendeley.com \\
        \hline
        ResearchGate & researchgate.net \\
        \hline
        SpringerLink & link.springer.com \\
        \hline
        Web of Science & access.clarivate.com \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}[H]{|l|l|X|l|l|l|}
    \caption{Literaturrecherche}\label{tbl:literaturrecherche} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Plattform} & \textbf{Abfrage} & \textbf{Literatur} & \textbf{H-Index} & \textbf{Q-Ranking} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
    \multicolumn{5}{|l|}{\leftarrow\ \tablename\ \thetable: Literaturrecherche} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Plattform} & \textbf{Abfrage} & \textbf{Literatur} & \textbf{H-Index} & \textbf{Q-Ranking} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline
    \multicolumn{5}{|r|}{Fortsetzung \rightarrow} \\
    \hline
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE!

Comment: thanks :D There is still a lot to learn at the moment. But I do manage to do a lot of things. But here and there, unfortunately, there are hiccups. @Zarko

Comment: Please extend your table code fragment to complete small document. As is, it contains errors.

Comment: @Zarko i added a complete example.

Comment: `\leftarrow` and `\rightarrow` have to be executed in math mode.

Comment: @Mico`\rightarrow` and `\leftarrow` works also without math mode.

Comment: @lublak - I guess you just don't care about `! Missing $ inserted.` warning messages...

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to achieve by loading the `floatrow` package.

Comment: @Mico i use vscode with Latex Workshop in combination with texlive and luatex. There is no warnings about missing $.  First of all, it is also important that everything works as it should. But when it is correct I put it between two dollar signs.

Comment: @lublak - Some editor front-ends are known to hide error and/or warning messages. Sadly [?], that does *not* guarantee that there are, in fact, no errors or other issues lurking in the code. See what happens if you switch to TeXworks as the front end.

Comment: `floatrow` and `caption` might not work well together and something is definitely screwing your captions. If in your example I add `captionskip=<v.sep>` to options of `floatrow` and then the following line to your preamble `\captionsetup[table]{position=top,skip=<v.sep>}` with the same `<v.sep>`, it seems consistent spacing between captions and tables. Try `v.sep` like `6pt` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this at the beginning of the xltabular:

```
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}[H]{|l|l|X|l|l|l|}
    \caption{Literaturrecherche}\label{tbl:literaturrecherche} \\[3ex]
    \hline
    \textbf{Plattform} & \textbf{Abfrage} & \textbf{Literatur} & \textbf{H-Index} & \textbf{Q-Ranking} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
```

[image]

Comment: This works. What is this 3ex? Do you perhaps have a link to it so that I can memorise it?

Comment: It's a typographical measure – 3 times the height of the letter x in the current font. An interline skip is about 4ex.

Comment: Btw 3.33ex works perfect. If I may ask you one more question. Do you also happen to know how I can fix the spacing over these tables? 
When I put text over it, the spacing between the text and the caption is different. ```testasdddddddddddddddddddddd
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}[H]{|l|l|X|l|l|l|}
 \caption{Literaturrecherche}\label{tbl:literaturrecherche} \\[3.3ex]
```

```testasdddddddddddddddddddddd
\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Plattformen}\label{tbl:plattformen}
```

Comment: @lublak: it is set with the `\abovecaptionskip` length, which defaults to 10pt.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following MWE (Minimal Working Example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip,
            font=small,
            labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|l|l|X|l|l|}
    \caption{Literaturrecherche}
    \label{tbl:literaturrecherche} \\
\hline
\textbf{Plattform}
    & \textbf{Abfrage} 
        & \textbf{Literatur} 
            & \textbf{H-Index} 
                & \textbf{Q-Ranking}    \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Literaturrecherche (cont.)}                                \\
    \hline
\textbf{Plattform}
    & \textbf{Abfrage}
        & \textbf{Literatur}
            & \textbf{H-Index}
                & \textbf{Q-Ranking}    \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline
\multicolumn{5}{r}{\footnotesize continue on the next page}\\
\endfoot
    \hline
\endlastfoot
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

Is this what you looking for. what is added and changed in comparison to your document example is marked in code by `% <---`.

As you can see, I left out `\leftarrow` and `\rightarrow` (which should be in math environment). I don't see any benefits using them. To my opinion is better to describe that table continue on the next page, as is done in above MWE.

**Edit:**
Sorry, after your edit of the question my proposed solution (considered `article` document class) doesn't work anymore. Apparently

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
```

overwrite caption `skip` option. So with this document class you should stick with @Bernard answer. or see, where `scrartcl` define caption style (I'm not familiar with this document class).

Comment: You may safely change `\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|l|l|X|l|l|l|}` to `\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|l|l|X|l|l|}`.

Comment: @Mico, hm but OP table has five columns ... I will check your sugestion.

Comment: But the vertical spacing is not fixed here i just removes the bold from the name.
The first table has a higher caption than the second table.

Comment: @lublak, sorry, but vertical space is fixed, i. e . reduced to `0.33\baselineskip`. If you not like this vertical space, write desired dimension to option `skip=...`. . Yes, I remove boldface from caption text. If you liked to have (I don't) than you can simply add this option: `font={small, bf}`, or if you not like to have small font in caption write just as you have `font=\bf, but than you can remove option `labelfont=bf`. BTW, all changes are marked and you can change according to your taste.

Comment: skip=0.33\baselineskip does not change the caption position of the xltabular. I jus tried my complete example. Both distances of the tables to their captions are not the same.

Comment: @lublak, see edited answer,

Comment: @Mico, indeed, it works also with defined only four columns. This is quite unexpected to me ...

Comment: @Zarko - I'm pretty sure all I did was to suggest defining 5 columns instead of 6.

Comment: @Mico, you are right. It seems that I should repeat elementary school and learn to count to ten again :-(. Corrected now. Thank you very much!